# Updating data on a Vue component shared between 2 routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

So basically, i have declared 2 different routes and set them to use the same component.
How do i go about updating the data (different API requests based on route) in this component.

I managed to make it work by calling a method `this.updateData` per say and calling this method on `created` lifecycle hook and also calling it on watching the `$route.path` property, and it works but it seems a dirty way to make it work to me, and i might be missing something.

Edit: Im using just Vue js for Simple Page Application, no other frameworks nothing fancy.

Comment: I suggest that you add some code.

Comment: Its more a logical question, but fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running to the same problem, vue.js tries to reuse components instances as much as it can so basically unless you have a `key` unique attribute on the component it will point to the same component instance.
So to have a different instance for everytime you use that component add a `key` attribute which has to be unique. e.g.

`<router-view v-bind:key="$router.path" />`

In this case it will use the path as a key so that for each route you use a shared component it will create a new instance and you can access the `created()` lifecycle hook on each one.